# How to use Threading in Change some Cell in Gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, multithreading

How do I use Threading to Change some Cell in Gridview? I have a query from database and it uses a lot of time for its query. So It's very slow and I would like to use Threading to load data faster. Also, when the thread has finished it's job can change data in Grid view?

Comment: Is the problem how to implement the threading or how to avoid Cross Thread exceptions when populating the grid?

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<Test>() { new Test { Name = "Original Value" } };
    }

    // Start the a new Task to avoid blocking the UI Thread
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(this.UpdateGridView);
    }
    // Blocks the UI
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateGridView();
    }

    private void UpdateGridView()
    {
        //Simulate long running operation
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Action del = () =>
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "Updated value";
            };
        // If the caller is on a different thread than the one the control was created on
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            dataGridView1.Invoke(del);
        }
        else
        {
            del();
        }
    }
}
```